# How can I grep YouTube video ID from the web?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if it was possible to get all the video IDs from a YouTube playlist pages and display them in a list.

```
<li class="playlist-video-item odd">
    <a href="/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0&amp;list=FLk8PLezsTU6MuuBxE5utNQw&amp;index=3" class="tile-link-block video-tile">
      <span class="video-index">3</span>

        <span class="playlist-video-item-base-content">
  <span class="thumb-container">
<span class="ux-thumb-wrap">
    <span class="video-thumb ux-thumb-114 "><span class="clip"><img src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/eVMWgmQA4Ig/default.jpg" alt="Thumbnail" ></span></span>
    <span class="video-time">3:37</span>
    <button type="button" class="addto-container addto-button short video-actions yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-short" onclick=";return false;" data-button-menu-id="shared-addto-menu" data-video-ids="oHg5SJYRHA0" data-button-action="yt.www.addtomenu.load" data-feature="thumbnail" role="button"><img class="yt-uix-button-icon yt-uix-button-icon-addto" src="//s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" alt=""><span class="yt-uix-button-content"><span class="addto-label hid">Add to</span></span><img class="yt-uix-button-arrow" src="//s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" alt=""></button>
</span>
```

As you can see the ID is here  `data-video-ids="oHg5SJYRHA0"`

Answer (score 5):

Rather than scraping the IDs from markup like that, you should probably take a look at the [YouTube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this to be done with jQuery, according to your tags.

```
$('span.ux-thumb-wrap button').data('video-ids')
```

Your example code only have one ID, so I wouldn't know how to create a list. Or what type of list for that matter. Please add a comment with further instrux as needed.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear. That's an example of a single track, they are listed in the source like that.

Comment: Okay. But you're probably better of following @Jaitsu's suggestion.